# Announcement: very old TOPIK results to be unavailable after July 2019

Tags: discussion

[TOPIK (Test of Proficiency In Korean)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_of_Proficiency_in_Korean) is the standardized Korean level test offered by the Ministry of Education in South Korea

Upto this point, the results of any TOPIK tests you have ever taken are available to view and download at the TOPIK website. They have recently announced that **after July 1st, 2019, only those TOPIK scores that still have their validity, will be available for download.** TOPIK scores are valid for 2 years after publication. So for instance, if you have a score for a TOPIK test you took in 2010 (valid until 2012), and one you took in 2018 (valid until 2020), you will only be able to view the score for the 2018 test after July 2019. Link to the announcement is given below:

http://topik.go.kr/usr/cmm/subLocation.do?menuSeq=2110501&boardSeq=68552

[image: Screenshot of announcement]

Until 2019-07-01, all the previous TOPIK scores are still available, so I suggest to download a copy now if necessary, before they get removed from the website.